# event.stopPropagation() not working on click event

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

In a part of my code (which is very extensive, so I will only show the applicable part), I have this:

```
$(".help."+help+" .left").click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
if (!moving){
  moving = 1;
  var move = $(".help."+help+" .all").css("left");
  move = parseInt(move.substr(0,move.length-2)) + 300;
  if (move <= 0)$(".help."+help+" .all").animate({left:move},{duration:300,complete:function(){moving = 0}})
  else moving = 0;
};
});
```

The `event.stopPropagation()` is to prevent this from being called:

```
$("html").click(function(){
alert("check");
$(".help").each(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("open")){
    $(this).removeClass("open").animate({opacity:0},{duration:500,complete:function(){
      $(this).css("display","none");
    }});
  };
});
});
```

This section is to close the "help box" when clicked off of it anywhere in the document.

The `event.stopPropagation()` is NOT working though. I put the `alert("check")` in there to make sure it was the issue, and it is.

The strange part? This next line of code IS working with `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$(".showhelp").click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
if ($(this).hasClass("materials"))help = "materials";
else help = "bearings";
if (!$(".help."+help).hasClass("open")){
  $(".help."+help).addClass("open").css("display","block").animate({opacity:1},200);
}else{
  $(".help."+help).removeClass("open").animate({opacity:0},{duration:200,complete:function(){
    $(this).css("display","none");
  }});
};
});
```

I hope this is enough information.

Comment: Are you sure the handler for `$(".help."+help+" .left").click(...)` is being called? Try a `console.log()` or `alert()` there.

Comment: Yes, it is being called. To double-check, I added an alert to see.

Comment: Have you tried `return false`

Comment: I have, no avail. This one has me completely stumped.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A7Wcb/ I pulled this straight from the site and tweaked slightly. So it's not exactly right, but you can get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I realized what the issue was. Had nothing to do with the stopPropagation(). Had to do with an undefined variable.

Issue is resolved. Thanks for your help though!